# Why doesn't message go to DLQ when retention period expire?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am using SQS and DLQ to process event. I recently found I am missing messages randomly. One possible reason is the retention period may be reached. But I can't see any messages in DLQ.

Based on AWS doc, it is not clear whether the message goes to DLQ after being deleted. Is there a way to monitor those expired messages?

```
You can configure the Amazon SQS message retention period to a value from 1 minute to 14 days. The default is 4 days. Once the message retention quota is reached, your messages are automatically deleted.
```

Comment: Messages are only sent to a DLQ after being received a set number of times without being deleted from the queue.  Messages that are deleted from the queue are not eligible to be sent to a DLQ.

Answer (score 0):

Hey the retention period actually signifies the maximum time period for which a message can stay alive in a queue and not the time after which the message will be sent to the DLQ.

There is a property called `Maximum Receives` which you can configure to a numeric value. What Maximum Receives signifies is the number of times the main SQS can receive a message back from the consumer on failures before moving that message to the DLQ (if configured)

Comment: if the message timed out before hitting the maximum receives, it won't be sent to DLQ right?